# Multiple Alamofire Request Issue with long JSON data

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a function httpGet:

```
func httpGet(phpPage: String!, parameters: NSDictionary!, callback: @escaping (NSArray) -> Void)
```

Inside this function I call Alamofire like this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.anypage.com", method: .post, parameters: mParameters as! [String: AnyObject], encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).validate().responseJSON { response in

                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):
                    if let data = response.result.value {

                        callback(data as! NSArray)

                    }

                case .failure(_):

                    print("Error message:\(String(describing: response.result.error))")

                    }
                    break

                }
            }
```

The problem is when I call the httpGet two times in different ViewControllers. If the first call, doesn't end I get in the second call a Empty JSON with error:

```
Error message:Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 500)))
```

How can I get the two calls to this function works at the same time, without this error?

Comment: Do you call with same parameters? Or to same endpoints? Status code 500 is not relevant your code. It is  about server, as you know.

Comment: Two different endpoints

Comment: So i think, you must check your parameters or headers.

Comment: But it works ok, both, when I do it separately. And if I wait until the long JSON data load completely, the other request works ok. The problem is when the two runs at the same time.

Comment: So server can't response to two request at the same time.

Comment: Yes, the server can.